# Microsoft Excel, Populating a list on sheet 1 with data from sheet 2 based on a second column on sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to make our meal planning spreadsheet smarter.

I'm using one of Excel's templates for now, and it's working for us after some modification.

I have "Recipe Index," "Meal Planner," "Shopping List," and multiple recipes as my sheets.

Recipe Index is a list of all the recipes. Meal Planner is a list of recipes for this week. Shopping list looks at Meal Planner for recipe names, then each recipe to pull ingredients and create a shopping list for the week.

I don't want to have to type what meals we are having every week into the Meal Planner sheet.

I would rather just mark those recipes with an "X" or something similar on the Recipe Index sheet and the names of those recipes populate on the Meal Planner, and their ingredients on the Shopping list.

I have been racking my brain on this one, but I cannot come up with a function to put into the Meal Planner sheet to search a column on the Recipe Index for an "X" and to copy the name from another column in Recipe Index to Meal Planner.

Any help is appreciated. I'll attach some screen shots in case I'm not as clear as I hope.

[Here is my Meal Planner sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKYXD.png)

[Here is my Recipe Index sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80eZh.png)

Comment: The screen shots you have included are insufficient to solve the issue since are just like picture since are template then it must have some codes applied as I can see for the meal planner sheet in column C drop down is applied !! better load the WB on cloud,  live sheet can be better to edit.

Comment: The drop down on the Meal Planner sheet is just the list of recipes on the Recipe Index. 

All that's required is the recipe name spelled as it is on the Recipe Index.

I'll see if I can upload a copy of the WB.

Comment: 1 . how is your ingredients are listed? ( in which cell/sheet + what is the source data structure looks like)  2. how does the final output looks like in shopping list? (since there is no printsceen, we can just assume.. and its not appropriate.. )